# What do you call words such as "distance", "duration", "price", "temperature", etc.?

Tags: vocabulary

What word do we use to call words that refer to an amount of something such as "distance", "duration", "price", "temperature", etc.?

Comment: I'd call them "metrics".

Comment: Nouns is what I'd call them.

Comment: @HotLicks +1, but perhaps one step removed from *metrics* proper.

Answer (score 0):

These might be called measurements.

Answer (score 0):

They are [quantitative](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quantitative) nouns.

> of or relating to the describing or measuring of quantity